# jQuery conflicts across separate functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just about get by when it comes to javascript - with the help of jQuery.

However, I came across a problem that changes what I thought about how jQuery elements are scoped.

The issue came to light because an element was getting a `margin-top` style applied, even though it's own code didn't have any way of doing so. On further investigation, I found another completely separate function was involved. Here's the two functions:

```
function docScroll() {
    var headerHeight = $("#app-header").outerHeight();
    var appBarHeight = $("#app-bar").outerHeight();

    $body = $("body");
    $content = $("#content");

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > appBarHeight) {
            $body.addClass("scrolled");
            $content.css("margin-top", headerHeight);
        }
        else {
            $body.removeClass("scrolled");
            $content.css("margin-top", "");
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see from the above function, it applies a `margin-top` value to a jQuery element named **$content**, which is defined inside the function.

```
$(".toggle-next").click(function () {
    $container = $(this).closest(".toggle-container");

    $container.toggleClass("toggle-active");

    $content = $container.children("ul");

    if ($content.css("max-height") !== "0px") {
        $content.css("max-height", "");
    }
    else {
        $content.css("max-height", $content[0].scrollHeight + "px");
    }
});
```

The above function applies a `max-height` value to an element also named **$content**, but once again, I assumed the element was scoped only within the function.

As you can see, the element name is the same ($content), but it represents different elements on the page, depending on the function.

**However,**

What I found was that the first function was applying the margin-top style (from the first function) to the $content element in the second function - in other words, **$content leaked between the two functions**.

I double checked the hierarchy - #content is a unique div, while the "ul", doesn't have an ID - so there was definitely no conflict through selecting the wrong element.

So I added a "var to the $content element and, lo and behold, it fixed the issue.

```
var $content = $("#content");
```

The question is why does **$content** leak but **var $content** doesn't? I appreciate it if anyone could explain the difference and why adding var fixed it.

Comment: It's because when you put `var` in front of it it will initialize the variable. If you don't it uses the existing variable declared elsewhere.

Comment: I'm guessing this was an edge case because I was clicking and potentially scrolling at the same time, while using the same variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not initialize a variable, it will treated as a global variable.

Example without initialization

```
function f() {
    a = 3;
}

f();

console.log(a); // Displays a 3
```

Example with initialization

```
function f2() {
    var b = 3;
}

f2();

console.log(b); // Error: b is not defined
```

My advice: **ALWAYS** initialize variables, either with **var**, **let** or **const**. It will save you headaches, since you are explicitly declaring its scope.

Comment: For some reason, I thought jQuery worked some magic behind the scenes for selectors.

Comment: jQuery offers you an API that does a lot for you, but it does not change the rules of the language.